# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed when using GitHub Actions and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, jestjs

While running my unit tests with GitHub Actions for my app cerate by Create React App using the Firebase Emulator I get an error

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1456#issuecomment-587529051

You need to [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#delete) the initialized Firebase app which "renders this app unusable and frees the resources of all associated services".

```js
afterAll(() => {
  firebase.app().delete();
});
```

Or use the `--forceExit` option when calling `react-scripts test`

```
...
"test": "react-scripts test",
"test-ci": "react-scripts test --forceExit",
...
```

Comment: The `firebase.app().delete()` didn't work for me, FWIW

Comment: Only use `--forceExit`. It's working with me.